# Join two columns in same file OR get rid of first occurring whitespace.

Tags: awk, sed

I have a very large file that looks like this:

```
chr1 345142 GACGGGGGTG/1
chr1 345241 GACGGGGGTG/2
chr1 569297 CGCCCCCCCC/1
chr1 569449 CGCCCCCCCC/2
```

I want it to look like this:

```
chr1345142 GACGGGGGTG/1
chr1345241 GACGGGGGTG/2
chr1569297 CGCCCCCCCC/1
chr1569449 CGCCCCCCCC/2
```

sed seems to take away both white spaces. Should I use awk?

Comment: What sed command did you use? `sed -e 's/ //' largeFile should work, maybe you added a g (global, all spaces in the line) ?

Comment: Thats's exactly what I did wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer was given as a comment:
The sed command should be used without a g flag.
Just use

```
sed -e 's/ //' largeFile
```

and not

```
sed -e 's/ //g' largeFile
```